# I want to remove 1.8.0_45 completely

Tags: jdk

I have this folder jdk 1.8.0_45 and there is a whole new desktop in it and all the other stuff and it messes with my downloads sometimes could somebody please help on removing it it won't remove just by rightclicking on it.
Here is a picture of it:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the output of `ls -la /usr/lib/jdk1.8.0_45` and `dpkg-query -S /usr/lib/jdk1.8.0_45`??

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're asking the question you really should, deleting this folder is probably not the right way to solve whatever you're trying to solve, but to answer your question:

**Deleting the folder from the Terminal:**

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Type `sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_45`

Then press enter, type your password and press enter once more.

Comment: still there, didn't work

Comment: Did it give you some kind of error?

Comment: No, It didn't give anything, when I typed it in and pressed enter it just let me type a new command nothing didn't happen at all

Comment: That's very odd. While it's typical that Unix programs like `rm` don't produce output on success and `-f` suppresses warning messages for missing files it doesn't suppress errors with different causes. Try running `rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives` as a regular user (i. e. without `sudo`) and see what happens (don't worry if that folder id deleted after all; it's only a cache for package downloads).